# Simpleimputer problem with array in python

Tags: python

I wanted to replace missing value with a simpleimputer to use bridge freqeunty. However, when I check to see if there are any nulls left. with is null () or then wants to check corr (). I get such an error

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Is there any chance to go back to the normal dataframe? because the whole set has become an array?

```
freq_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
train = freq_imputer.fit_transform(train)
train.isnull().sum()
```

Comment: So basically what you want is to convert the array into a dataframe?

Comment: The best I would like to replace categorical data gaps with most freqently. I tried it with a simple imputer but the dataframe turns into an array for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well  from what i could understand of your question you want to do the following.

First:
You need to make sure, that the imputer, subsitute specific nan values. Actually a good practice.

if array:

```
freq_imputer = SimpleImputer(np.nan,strategy='most_frequent')
```

if pandas:

```
freq_imputer = SimpleImputer(pd.na,strategy='most_frequent')
```

Really doesnt matter just substitute accordingly.

Now when it comes to the matter, of checking null values.

if array:

```
filt = lamda d: d['Column_being_checked'] == 0 or np.nan etc
map(filt,your_array)
#If this returns anything your got yourself some nans
```

if pandas:

```
your_dataframe['Series'].isnull().value_counts()
```

If you want to convert evertything  to a pd.Dataframe class, well you are going to have to utilize this constructor on top of the returned array.

```
pd.Dataframe(your_array,['Col1',...])
```

Comment: pd.na ? What you mean here ?

Comment: I meant pandas.na the equivalentt, to np.nan basically null values